# Google endpoints java Oauth/Oauth2 complete example

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

After reading a lot of links :
im not able to solve the workaround about issue from getuser=null on server side.
I need a complete example server side (app engine java) and client side (android app).
In some links people say : Save the user to datastore and bring it back. But i cant save the user...because it is  always  null...

```
package com.example.ismab_000.myapplication.backend;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException;
import com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthService;
import com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;

import javax.inject.Named;

/**
* An endpoint class we are exposing
*/
@Api(           name = "myApi",
version = "v1",
scopes = {Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE},
clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID,         Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,Constants.IOS_CLIENT_ID},
            audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE},
            namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain =   "backend.myapplication.ismab_000.example.com", ownerName = "backend.myapplication.ismab_000.example.com", packagePath = ""))

public class MyEndpoint {

    User user = null;
    MyBean response = new MyBean();
    String email;

/**
 * A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back
 */

@ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String name) {
/*
    try {
        OAuthService oauth = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();
        user = oauth.getCurrentUser();

    } catch (OAuthRequestException e) {
        // The consumer made an invalid OAuth request, used an access token    that was
        // revoked, or did not provide OAuth information.
        // ...
        response.setData("Hola desde Metodo1, " + name);
    }

 */
    email= user.getEmail();

    //response.setData("Hi, " + name + user.getEmail().toString());
    response.setData("Hi, desde APYSAYHI...");
    return response;
}
@ApiMethod(name = "Metodo1")
public MyBean metodo1(@Named("name") String name) {

    response.setData("Hola desde Metodo1, " + name);
    return response;
}
@ApiMethod(name = "Metodo2")
public MyBean metodo2(@Named("name") String name) {

    response.setData("Hola desde Metodo2, " + name);
    return response;
}


}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the User object you first need to configure the Endpoint to use OAuth. Instructions found here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth

OAuth means you'll need to configure the Project to to have the correct client IDs configured under the Constants object you are referring to when defining the API.

You then need to add the User object to the Endpoint method, e.g.:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String name, User user) throws OAuthRequestException, IOException {
```

> If an incoming client request has no authorization token or an invalid
>   one, user is null. In your code, you need to check whether user is
>   null and do ONE of the following, depending on the condition:
>
> - If the user is non-null, perform the authorized action.
> - If the user is null, throw an OAuthRequestException.
> - Alternatively, if the user is null, perform some action for an    unauthorized client access if some sort of unauthorized access is
>     desired.

Comment: At the moment, its not possible to determinate a user at server side GAE. Google get a valid credential at client side and make a valid request to api...but at endpoint side, user is always example.gmail.com.   Google is working to solve the problem of get user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have generated you clientIds (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth#Creating_OAuth_20_client_IDs), make sure you also update the *_CLIENT_ID Strings in Constants.java:

If you created the project from a maven archetype, the values will appear as follows:

```
public static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "replace this with your web client application ID";
public static final String ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = "replace this with your Android client ID";
public static final String IOS_CLIENT_ID = "replace this with your iOS client ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
Just getting a new values to CLIENT_ID and WEB_ID. 
The problem now is an issue to get email user at backend.
At endpoint...user!=null but always is example.google.com.

Google is working to solve.